# MFC Accelerator resource ID conflicts?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, mfc, resources

Someone change the numerical value of one of the accelerator in the resource.h file and because of that the accelerator stopped working.

(old value that was working)

```
#define IDR_DELETE_FROM_ACCELERATOR 32873
```

(new value that is not working)

```
#define IDR_DELETE_FROM_ACCELERATOR     22873
```

related code :

```
ON_COMMAND( IDR_DELETE_FROM_ACCELERATOR, OnDeleteFromAccelerator )

void CMyViewClass::OnDeleteFromAccelerator()
{
///....
}
```

In both cases, the numerical values are unique (no conflict).

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx), It seems that both numerical values should be valid.

Am I reading/understanding this correctly?

I can simply renumber the value to the one that worked, but I would like to understand why it stopped working.

Thanks,

Max.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project? Sometimes resources and code become out of sync.

Comment: Yes, I did rebuild (and deleted all temporary files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [TN020](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx) paying more attention.

On the table it is stated:

```
ID_            commands              0x8000 through 0xDFFF
```

0x8000 in decimal is 32768.

22873 is lower than that.